# Appending rows to DataFrame within a Loop

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am attempting to add a new a row to a dataframe over every iteration of a loop.

I want to estimate a model using my training set, record the estimate, and continually add the results to a dataframe while adding a new observation to my training set.

Here is my code thus far

```
forecast.table <- tibble()


colnames(forecast.table) <- c('.model', 'Quarter', 
                              'demeaned.d1.ln.Finished', '.mean')


for(i in c(0:32)){
  
  df.training.loop <- df[1:(which(as.character(df$Quarter) == '2000 Q1')+i), 
                           c('Quarter', 'demeaned.d1.ln.Finished')]
  
  model <- df.training.loop %>% 
    model(ARIMA(demeaned.d1.ln.Finished ~ pdq(3,0,0) + PDQ(0,0,0),
                fixed = list(ar1 = 0.387, ar2 = 0.206, ar3 = 0.226)))
  
  forecast <- model %>%
    forecast(h=1)
  

  
  forecast.table <- rbind(forecast.table, forecast)  

}
```

So basically my thinking was to create a empty dataframe and then begin the loop trying to add the row of the dataframe (forecast) to the empty dataframe.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: your initiation of `forecast.table` is 0x 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is the following:

```
forecast.table <- NULL

for(i in c(0:32)){
  
  df.training.loop <- df[1:(which(as.character(df$Quarter) == '2000 Q1')+i), 
                           c('Quarter', 'demeaned.d1.ln.Finished')]
  
  model <- df.training.loop %>% 
    model(ARIMA(demeaned.d1.ln.Finished ~ pdq(3,0,0) + PDQ(0,0,0),
                fixed = list(ar1 = 0.387, ar2 = 0.206, ar3 = 0.226)))
  
  forecast <- model %>%
    forecast(h=1)
  
  forecast.table <- bind_rows(forecast.table, forecast)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to do this in `lapply` to loop over the the range of values from 0 to 32, subset the dataset 'df', construct the `model`, get the `forecast` and `rbind` the `list` elements with `do.call`

```
forecast.table <- do.call(rbind, lapply(0:32, function(i) {
     df.training.loop <-   df[1:(which(as.character(df$Quarter) == '2000 Q1')+i), 
                       c('Quarter', 'demeaned.d1.ln.Finished')]
      model <- df.training.loop %>% 
model(ARIMA(demeaned.d1.ln.Finished ~ pdq(3,0,0) + PDQ(0,0,0),
            fixed = list(ar1 = 0.387, ar2 = 0.206, ar3 = 0.226)))

  forecast <- forecast(model, h = 1)
 forecast
      }))
```

---

Initializing with `tibble()` creates a 0 x 0 tibble and thus the column names are not getting assigned

```
forecast.table <- tibble()
```